# TypeError: MyApp is not a constructor, when using webpack 2 to create library and export es6 class

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

My goal is to create a myapp.min.js file, that can be included in a website, and then, anywhere below on that page a file can can call.

```
const newInstance = new MyApp(userOptionsObject);
```

However, I keep getting a **is not a constructor error**. Here is the relevant part of my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, ''),
  devtool: debug ? "cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "source-map",
  entry: ["./js/MyApp.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: 'myapp.min.js',
    library: 'MyApp',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  },
};
```

my MyApp.js looks like this:

```
export default class MyApp {
  constructor(userOps) {
    this.userOps = userOps;
  }
  toString() {
    return 'Hello visitor';
  }
}
```

So, inside a browser I would encounter for example:

```
  <script src="myapp.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var newInstance = new MyApp({some: "options"});
  </script>
```

Here is also my babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
      ["es2015", { "loose": true, "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: You whole library is named `MyApp` so if it is the default export, you'd probably need to do `new MyApp.default({some: "options"})`. This is a good case where using your debugging console to inspect the value would answer this quickly.

Comment: @loganfsmyth hm is this because I'm using export default instead of simply export?

Comment: @loganfsmyth using MyApp.default({some: "options"}) still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: had the same issue, using `var newInstance = new MyApp.default({some: "options"});`. worked for me